# How to add multiple labels to a node in Neo4J when using Neo4jImport.bat

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4jImport.bat to perform my initial database load.  I have a node file that looks like this:

```
application_id:ID(application_id),:LABEL
2036983247,application_id
2037028183,application_id
```

I would like to (sometimes) add a second `:suspect` label to some of these rows.  For example:

```
application_id:ID(application_id),:LABEL
2036983247,"application_id,suspect"
2037028183,application_id
```

Using the above format, the files will load successfully, however, when I try and query the data using cypher I run into issues.  Specifically, the below queries return 0 results:

```
match (n:application_id {application_id:"2036983247"}) return *
match (n:suspect) return *
```

Whilst the query against the row with a single label works fine:

```
match (n:application_id {application_id:"2037028183"}) return *
```

To make it more confusing, the `labels()` function seems to correctly show the labels as expected being returned in an array for the app with multiple labels.

According to [the import documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/import-tool-header-format.html) on labels:

> LABEL
>       Read one or more labels from this field. For multiple labels, the values are separated by the array delimiter.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The array delimiter defaults to `;` so use that to separate labels. No need for the quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each :LABEL column can have multiple labels in them, separated by whatever --array-delimiter specifies (defaults to ';'). Also, as Robert mentioned, multiple :LABEL columns is also supported.

Answer (score 2):

To add additional labels to a node, simply add an additional `:LABEL` header column for each additional label you wish to add.

```
application_id:ID(application_id),:LABEL,:LABEL
```

In the contents of the file, you then delimit your labels with whatever delimiter you are using:

```
2036983247,application_id,suspect
2037028183,application_id
```

Unlike properties, it seems that the import tool will allow `:LABEL` columns to be 'missing' (at least if they're the last column).

Comment: Seems like while this works, it may not exactly be 'supported'.  Best to use the approach Mattias suggests below.